# Help solving $\oint _{C} \frac{e^{3z}}{(z-\ln{2})^{4}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I've been trying to solve this problem but have a few questions regarding the final steps. I've been using this formula here $$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint _{C} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$

and finding $\oint _{C} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{n!}f^{(n)}(a) =$ was relatively easy. I am stuck on how to find $f(a)$ however. When integrating do I still include constants so that $f(a)=\frac{1}{27}e^{3a}+c_1a^{2}+c_2a+c_3$? If so how do I find what the constants are? C is the square with vertices $\pm1 \pm i$.

Comment: The answer is precisely what the formula gives. Which constants are you referring to? The contour description comes in for the formula, not for finding additional constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need $\oint _{C} \frac{e^{3z}}{(z-\ln{2})^{4}}dz$.
You have the formula
$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint _{C} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz.$$
Here $a= \ln 2$, $n=3$ and $f(z)=e^{3z}$. Since $f^{(3)}(z)=27e^{3z}$, then
$$\oint _{C} \frac{e^{3z}}{(z-\ln{2})^{4}}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{3!} \cdot f^{(3)}(\ln 2)=\frac{\pi i}{3}\cdot(27e^{3(\ln 2)})=\frac{\pi i}{3}\cdot(27\cdot 2^3)=72 \pi i.$$

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's integral formula, $n=3$, $a=\ln 2$, and $f(z)=e^{2z}$. Thus

\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{e^{3z}}{(z-\ln 2)^4}dz&=2\pi i \bigg(f^{(3)}(e^{3z})\bigg\vert_{z=\ln 2} \bigg)\\
&=2 \pi i \bigg(27e^{3z}\bigg\vert_{z=\ln 2} \bigg)\\
&=2 \pi i \bigg( 27 \cdot 2^3\bigg)\\
&=72 \pi i.
\end{align}